# Easy way to get subset of string[] in C#

Tags: c#

In python I am trying to just do `object[1:]`, skipping the first element and then returning the rest of the `string[]`. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6):

Now would be a good time to learn about LINQ - you want `Skip(1)` to skip the first element. Then you can use `ToArray` to create an array if you really need to. For example:

```
string[] original = { "a", "b", "c" };
IEnumerable<string> skippedFirst = original.Skip(1);
foreach (string x in skippedFirst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // b then c
}
string[] skippedFirstAsArray = skippedFirst.ToArray();
```